# Terminar um loop quando for digitada determinada string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu estou tentando preencher uma lista com números, para isso fiz um *loop*:

```
lista=[]
i = float(input())
lista.append(i)

while (i != '.'):
    i = float(input())
    lista.append(i)
```

Porém eu queria que, ao colocar a string `"."`, o *loop* finalizasse, de forma que o ponto não aparecesse na lista.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em vez de chamar `input` duas vezes (uma fora do `while` e outra dentro), faça isso uma vez só:

```
lista = []
while True:
    i = input('Digite um número (ou "." para encerrar): ')
    if i == '.':
        break # sai do while
    try: # tenta converter para float
        lista.append(float(i))
    except ValueError: # se deu erro na conversão, mostra mensagem de erro
        print('Você não digitou um número válido')

print(lista)
```

`while True` é um *loop* "infinito", que só é interrompido por [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement) -  e eu só chamo o `break` se for digitado `.`, que é a condição de saída. Assim você evita ter que chamar `input` duas vezes (se a mensagem precisar ser mudada, por exemplo, você só precisará mudar em um lugar - [não repita as coisas sem necessidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/112052))

Se não foi digitado um ponto, eu tento converter para número e adicionar na lista.

Caso não tenha sido digitado um número válido, eu capturo o `ValueError` e mostro uma mensagem de erro (e nesse caso, o número não é adicionado na lista).

Repare que, ao contrário do que fez a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/484253/112052), não precisa usar `str(input())`, pois [`input` já retorna uma string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), então usar `str` aqui é redundante e desnecessário.

E usar [`isnumeric`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) esconde algumas armadilhas: há vários caracteres para os quais `isnumeric` retorna `True` mas dão erro ao converter para `float`, [veja aqui](https://ideone.com/IrMYBf). O melhor é usar logo `float` e capturar o [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) para saber se não foi digitado um número.

Answer (score 2):

Você definiu a variável `i` como **float** (automaticamente ***o valor passado tem que ser float, não pode ser string ou booleano***), o `.` é uma string, e quando o usuário tenta passar essa string ao invés do float o python gera o erro de valor (ValueError)

O código ficaria assim:

```
lista=[]
i = str(input('Digite um número: ("." para parar):'))
if i.isnumeric() == True: # Verifica se o valor passado é um número
    lista.append(float(i)) # Adiciona o float do número a lista

while (i != '.'):
    i = str(input('Digite um número: ("." para parar):'))
    if i.isnumeric() == True:
        lista.append(float(i))
```

E da maneira pythônica, mais correta e visualmente bonita assim:

```
lista = [] # Define a lista

while True: # Entra em loop infinito
    i = str(input('Digite um número: ("." para parar):')).strip() # Capta o que o usuário digitar e no fim remove os espaços em branco (se tiver)
    if i == '.': # Verifica se o valor passado é a condição de parada, se sim ele para
        break
    else:
        if i.isnumeric() == True: # Verifica se o valor passado é um número
            lista.append(float(i)) # Adiciona o float do número a lista
```

Comment: nossa muito obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu tava precisando, não conhecia o uso do isnumeric por isso não tava conseguindo.

Comment: Há outras maneiras de detectar se o valor passado é um número ou não, mas o mais viável até o presente momento é o .isnumeric(), há muitas coisas no python que facilitam nosso trabalho, e essa é uma delas haha

Comment: @Paulo Thiago, o input que captura o valor da variável  `i` não precisa da função `str`. Pois, o input já passa o valor digitado como string. Neste caso, a função  `str` torna-se redundante. Abraço.

Comment: @JediNegão Só um detalhe: há vários caracteres para os quais `isnumeric` retorna `True` mas dão erro ao converter para `float`, [veja aqui](https://ideone.com/IrMYBf). O melhor é usar logo `float` e capturar o `ValueError` para saber se não foi digitado um número (como eu fiz na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/484258/112052))

Comment: @Solkarped Usei o `str(input())` só para explicitar e deixar claro para o @Jedi Negão mesmo, mas no geral é sim menos redundante usar só o `input()`, como você mesmo disse. Abraço

Comment: @hkotsubo Para esta situação o .`isnumeric()` serviu bem, mas é como você disse, há vários valores que ele acaba retornando `True`, por isso sua resposta acaba sendo também muito viável

Comment: @PauloThiago Só servirá bem se o usuário não digitar nenhum desses caracteres problemáticos que mencionei.Tudo bem que não são caracteres muito comuns no nosso dia-a-dia, mas se vc está lendo entradas do usuário, é melhor estar preparado para receber "qualquer coisa" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Realmente tiveram respostas muito boas, utéis e funcionais então vou apenas falar novamente algumas coisas iguais aos outros

1 - Se você define o input como float, não tens como receber uma string pois ao ser recebido a mensagem, já será convertido, porém daria erro tentar converter ".".A melhor solução seria verificar se é um número mais tarde

2 - Você poderia simplesmente ter colocado como um loop infinito para poder diminuir o tamanho do programa, mas não é obrigatório

3 - Não sei se isso é da sua IDE, mas fica de olho pois no python não se utiliza () quando vai dar uma condição "while (i!='.'):" isto em python não acontece

Chega de enrolação, mostrarei como a minha solução ficou:

**Apenas valor quebrado**

```
lista=[]
while True:
   i = input('Digite um número (ou "." para encerrar): ').replace(',','.')
   """Aquele replace caso tenha uma , ele irá substituir por . para poder converter 
      para float"""
   if i[0].isnumeric() and '.' in i:
      #Aqui especificamos que para poder ser adicionado é apenas um número quebrado
      #Se digitar um inteiro não será adicionado
      #O .isnumeric vai verificar se a primeira palavra (i[0]) é um número
      i = float(i)
      lista.append(i)
   else:
      if i=='.':
         print(lista)
         exit('Obrigado por usar o programa!')
         #uma forma mais rápida de sair do programa sem usar print
      else:
         print('Por favor digite algo válido')
```

**Qualquer número**

```
lista=[]
while True:
   i = input('Digite um número (ou "." para encerrar): ').replace(',','.')
   if i[0].isnumeric():
      #Mas para ser adicionado ainda é necessário que pelo menos comece com um número
      i = float(i)
      lista.append(i)
   else:
      if i=='.':
         print(lista)
         break
      else:
         print('Por favor digite algo válido')
 print('Obrigado por usar o programa')
 #apenas para demonstrar a funcionalidade do exit()
```

A falha desse programa é caso alguém digite um número e em seguida letras, para evitar que dê problema, você poderia usar o try:

**Impossibilitanto erros**

```
 lista=[]
    while True:
       i = input('Digite um número (ou "." para encerrar): ').replace(',','.')
       if i[0].isnumeric():
          try:
             i = float(i)
             lista.append(i)
          except:
             print('Digite um número válido')
       else:
          if i=='.':
             print(lista)
             break
          else:
             print('Por favor digite apenas números válidos')
 print('Obrigado por usar o programa')
```